# Facebook comments doesn't work in html

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

Hi I'm tying to put a like button in my web but I have a problem with that, I'm using the code below

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>


<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/petsandfashion?fref=ts" data-width="500px" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

But this doesn't work and appear an error "GET file://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js". My question is I need put something more?, other script or call another function or something more?.

I put in the script this "js.src = "**https:**//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1";"
but Is it fine?.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

> error "GET file://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js".

this caused by you accessed your `index.html` on browser using `file:///` protocol instead of `http://` or `https://`.

> I put in the script this "js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1";" but Is it fine?.

You better remove it, for example if a user was visiting your page on `http://` the js sdk will called on `http://`.

The same thing happens for a visitor accessing your site on `https://` it will load it `https://`

Comment: Ok, then I need prove this in a sever. Thanks